# Matplotlib polar does not plot as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to insert a polar plot "version" of a cartesian plot. Here's what it should look like (according to a similar program done in Matlab):

[image]

And here's enough of the code to show the weirdness I'm getting:

```
from scipy import pi, sin, cos, log
from numpy import radians as rad
from numpy import log10, linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


############## Inputs ##############

#Beamwidth, in degrees
BW = 5

############## Constants for calculations ##############
# 0 = uniform/sin, 1 = cos, 2 = cos^2, etc


#Peak Pattern break points, from Table 3
p0, p1, p2, p3, p4 = -5.75, -14.4, -22.3, -31.5, -39.4


#Average pattern break points, from Table 3
a0, a1 ,a2, a3, a4 = -12.16, -20.6, -29, -37.6, -42.5


#Constant added to peak pattern to convert it to average, from Table 3
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4 = -3.72, -4.32, -4.6, -4.2, -2.61


#Mask floor levels, from Table 3
floor0, floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4 = -30, -50, -60, -70, -80


############## Calculations ##############

#Lists for plotting purposes

u_x = list(linspace(0,90,500))

u0_norm_y = list()
u0_peak_y = list()
u0_avg_y = list()

##Calculations start

for ang in u_x: 

########## Uniform

    u0 = pi * 50.8 * sin(rad(ang)) / BW

    def u0_norm(ang):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 20 * log10(abs(sin(u0) / u0))


    def u0_peak(ang, u0_norm):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        elif u0_norm(ang) > p0:
            return u0_norm(ang)
        elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) > floor0:
            return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW)
        else:
            return floor0

    def u0_avg(ang, u0_norm):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        elif u0_norm(ang) > a0:
            return u0_norm(ang)
        elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0 > floor0:
            return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0
        else:
            return floor0 

    u0_peak_y.append(u0_peak(ang, u0_norm))
    u0_norm_y.append(u0_norm(ang))
    u0_avg_y.append(u0_avg(ang, u0_norm))

############## Plots ##############

#Uniform
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, polar = True)

ax1.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")

ax1.set_title("Uniform Pattern")
ax1.set_xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Normalized Antenna Pattern (dB)")

ax2.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")
ax2.set_thetamin(0)
ax2.set_thetamax(90)



ax1.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.4)

plt.show()
```

Obviously, something has gone terribly wrong. My plot is an actual mess. I'm assuming something about the way polar plots are created vs cartesian plots, code-wise, is very different, but I haven't been able to find any real detail about this.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more words than "weirdness"? Possibly you just forgot to convert degrees to radiants?

Comment: The plot that my code creates is actual nonsense. It literally just looks like scribbles. Using the same math to create the cartesian plot works perfectly, but plugging it directly into polar is apparently not the way to go. Some input is apparently horribly wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Again, did you just forgot to convert degrees to radiants?

Comment: To do the debug I'd start by simplifying the code. Put the function definitions outside of the for cycle (you can pass u0 as input argument to uo_norm). Also it looks like u0_norm is a function but also a variable, which might not be the problem but it definitely contribute to complicate reading the code to spot the error.

Comment: Not that I know of. Sin, cos, etc, all need radians, so those conversions are all built into my equations. The polar plot does seem to be using degrees, though, since setting the theta axis to show 0 - 90 gives me a 90 degree wedge. Outside of trig functions, everything is calculated using a degree value, which would seem to make sense, at least math-wise.

Comment: For example: why are you passing u0_norm to u0_peak()? If you're passing a variable then it's not used. If you're passing a function...well you don't need to.

Comment: @Robyc The answer is probably because I'm a physicist more than a programmer. Math functions and code functions are very, very different and I constantly get mixed up. I'm still learning how to mesh the two ways of thinking, which means a lot of silly mistakes and unnecessary code... I'll look at paring that down a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up radians and degrees (the intuition of ImportanceOfBeingErnest was correct).
Remove the conversion to radians you do when defining u0 and convert to radians directly the input u_x.

```
from scipy import pi, sin, cos, log
from numpy import radians as rad
from numpy import log10, linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


############## Inputs ##############

#Beamwidth, in degrees
BW = 5

############## Constants for calculations ##############
# 0 = uniform/sin, 1 = cos, 2 = cos^2, etc


#Peak Pattern break points, from Table 3
p0, p1, p2, p3, p4 = -5.75, -14.4, -22.3, -31.5, -39.4


#Average pattern break points, from Table 3
a0, a1 ,a2, a3, a4 = -12.16, -20.6, -29, -37.6, -42.5


#Constant added to peak pattern to convert it to average, from Table 3
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4 = -3.72, -4.32, -4.6, -4.2, -2.61


#Mask floor levels, from Table 3
floor0, floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4 = -30, -50, -60, -70, -80

############## Calculations ##############

#Lists for plotting purposes

u_x = list(linspace(0,rad(90),500))


u0_norm_y = list()
u0_peak_y = list()
u0_avg_y = list()

##Calculations start

for ang in u_x:

########## Uniform

    u0 = pi * 50.8 * sin((ang)) / BW

    def u0_norm(ang):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 20 * log10(abs(sin(u0) / u0))


    def u0_peak(ang, u0_norm):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        elif u0_norm(ang) > p0:
            return u0_norm(ang)
        elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) > floor0:
            return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW)
        else:
            return floor0

    def u0_avg(ang, u0_norm):
        if ang == 0:
            return 0
        elif u0_norm(ang) > a0:
            return u0_norm(ang)
        elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0 > floor0:
            return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0
        else:
            return floor0

    u0_peak_y.append(u0_peak(ang, u0_norm))
    u0_norm_y.append(u0_norm(ang))
    u0_avg_y.append(u0_avg(ang, u0_norm))

############## Plots ##############

#Uniform
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, polar = True)

ax1.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")

ax1.set_title("Uniform Pattern")
ax1.set_xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Normalized Antenna Pattern (dB)")

ax2.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")
ax2.set_thetamin(0)
ax2.set_thetamax(90)



ax1.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Here is what I think is a better version of the same code, with little edits.

```
from scipy import pi, sin, cos, log
from numpy import radians as rad
from numpy import log10, linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


############## Inputs ##############

#Beamwidth, in degrees
BW = 5

############## Constants for calculations ##############
# 0 = uniform/sin, 1 = cos, 2 = cos^2, etc


#Peak Pattern break points, from Table 3
p0, p1, p2, p3, p4 = -5.75, -14.4, -22.3, -31.5, -39.4


#Average pattern break points, from Table 3
a0, a1 ,a2, a3, a4 = -12.16, -20.6, -29, -37.6, -42.5


#Constant added to peak pattern to convert it to average, from Table 3
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4 = -3.72, -4.32, -4.6, -4.2, -2.61


#Mask floor levels, from Table 3
floor0, floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4 = -30, -50, -60, -70, -80


############## Calculations ##############

#Lists for plotting purposes

u_x = list(linspace(0,rad(90),500))


u0_norm_y = list()
u0_peak_y = list()
u0_avg_y = list()

##Function definition
def u0_norm(ang, u0):
    if ang == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 20 * log10(abs(sin(u0) / u0))


def u0_peak(ang, u0):
    if ang == 0:
        return 0
    elif u0_norm(ang, u0) > p0:
        return u0_norm(ang, u0)
    elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) > floor0:
        return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW)
    else:
        return floor0


def u0_avg(ang, u0):
    if ang == 0:
        return 0
    elif u0_norm(ang, u0) > a0:
        return u0_norm(ang, u0)
    elif -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0 > floor0:
        return -8.584 * log(2.876 * ang / BW) + c0
    else:
        return floor0

for ang in u_x:

    ########## Uniform

    u0 = pi * 50.8 * sin(ang) / BW

    u0_peak_y.append(u0_peak(ang, u0))
    u0_norm_y.append(u0_norm(ang, u0))
    u0_avg_y.append(u0_avg(ang, u0))

    ############## Plots ##############

#Uniform
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, polar = True)

ax1.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax1.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")

ax1.set_title("Uniform Pattern")
ax1.set_xlabel("Angle (radians)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Normalized Antenna Pattern (dB)")

ax2.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_norm_y, label= "Normalized Pattern")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_peak_y, label= "Peak")
ax2.plot(u_x, u0_avg_y, label= "Average")
ax2.set_thetamin(0)
ax2.set_thetamax(90)



ax1.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.4)

plt.show()
```

Comment: So putting u_x itself in radians changes the way u0_peak and u0_avg were plotting (graphically, they moved way up when they need to trace along the curve) so there'd need to be some further changes, but just converting u_x to radians in the plot portion of the polar graph only does fix the problem, so thank you! I guess the math is all in radians where the display is in degrees... Also, I appreciate your edits! It really helps me better understand how all this works together.

Comment: yes I can see that from a mathematical point of view there is still something to fix. For example it just popped to my eyes that the beamwidth BW is expressed in degrees so ang/BW doesn't make sense as it is. 
An additional suggestion: if you need to write the same constant 3 times and use it in your calculations...you might want to assign that number to a variable with a good name (possibly self-explanatory, at least in your domain). I refer to  -8.584, 2.876... 
This will help you avoid mistakes, save time if you need to make changes, and have a kind of self-documented code.